# Upload React Native application to App Store without application Loader

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store

I am trying to upload my app that was built in react-native to the app store but Application Loader is no longer used in Xcode anyone knows what I need to do. All of the only sources I found were using Application Loader

Answer (score 1):

It's the same process, but using Transporter when it comes to upload the `ipa` file

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12